# d3.js map inset (zoom)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'm trying to draw a map with d3.js that has a portion of the city map offset and drawn in a different location (a map inset). Are there working examples of this using d3.js? If not, would I just use a different .json file, create a DOM element, load the main map normally and after load the secondary data for the inset?

Preferably a working example would be helpful, but if nothing exists I'll try to edit in what I figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at a similar task, but not done yet. My initial thought was to define a composite projection like albersUsa described [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections).  You can see how it works from the [implementation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/geo/albers-usa.js) - it basically defines three different projections from (lon,lat) => (x,y), and then chooses which to use based on the lat/lon of the source point.

But I'm not sure that'll work out of the box for insets because the different projections would overlap - for example a road coming from some far-off place to your inset city would go up to the edge of the unmagnified city, and then restart farther back at the edge of the magnified view. So you'd need to customize the clipping so that the base projection gets clipped at the edge of the magnified inset boundary (in screen coords) rather than at the edge of the inset boundary in (lon, lat) coords.  Effectively there is a region of the map that doesn't get rendered because it's hidden by the expanded inset.

Comment: Here's an example of a naive approach that just redraws the map for each inset using a new projection, clipped to whatever size you want: http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/40e8e58359dfc852ee19